# (Python) Getting maximum recursion error, should I try another method or override it in this case?

Tags: python, sockets, recursion

I'm writing files from a socket using recursion and I can see why I'm getting a maximum recursion error. My question is, should I ignore it?

Here is the desired behavior:

- For the first data chunk, overwrite or create a file open in "wb" mode. For every remaining data chunk, append. If I don't do this, it will append data to an existing file if in "ab" mode, or it will only write each chunk to its own file in "wb" mode.

Here is my solution:

```
def write_file(path:str, client_socket:socket, recv_len: int = 1, open_mode: str = "wb"):
    if recv_len:
        data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
        recv_len = len(data)

        with open(path, open_mode) as f:
            f.write(data)

        if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN:
            client_socket.send("File successfully transfered.")
            return
        else:
            write_file(path, client_socket, recv_len, "ab")
```

Here is my previous, less elegant solution that also works:

```
def download(path, client_socket):
    while True:
            file_buffer = b""
            recv_len = 1
                    
            
            try:
                while recv_len:
                    data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
                    recv_len = len(data)

                    # Overwrite file if exists.
                    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(data)

                    if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN:
                        break

                    else:
                        while True:
                            data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
                            recv_len = len(data)

                            # Append rest of data chunks
                            with open(path, 'ab') as f:
                                f.write(data)

                            if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN:
                                break
                    break

                if not data:
                    break

                client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")

            except:
                client_socket.send(b"File transfer failed.")
```

My recursive solution works for files up to around 80GB if I add this line:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
```

Something tells me I'm gonna hear a lot of "Well that limit is there for a good reason", which I don't doubt. But since my looped solution feels sloppy and wacky, and my recursive one goes into this huge recursive adventure - what would be the better way to move forward? Is there another alternative I'm not seeing?

Edit: I omitted the Try, Except from the recursive model just to see if it would work. I plan on putting them back in.

Edit: I am also not closing sockets after the transfer, making a `not data` state not something I can utilize.

Comment: In your first example *(with recursion)* using default `mode` you overwrite previous chunk every time function called and generally it's quite ineffective to reopen file every iteration.

Comment: I'm passing in "ab" as the mode for the recursive call.

Comment: I can't see how your two solutions are equivalent. Your iterative one is able to catch some exceptions. I'm sure that a recursive approach is wrong because the exit depends on external data. However, I'm also sure that your iterative one could be a *lot* more tidy.

Comment: True, I did leave out the try/except for the recursive version just because I wanted to see if it would work, first. Which it did save for the maximum recursion error.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion solution for this is problematic, as it opens the same file multiple times which can lead to errors.

The `while` approach is the correct approach, it should just be implemented correctly.

You should be opening the file once, then call `socket.recv` until it's empty. While it is not empty, write to the file. Close the file in the end (or use `with open`).

```
def write_file(path:str, client_socket:socket, open_mode: str = "wb"):
    with open(path, open_mode) as f:
        data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
        while data:
            f.write(data)
            data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
    client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")
```

In Python >= 3.8 this can be simplified further using the assignment expression (`:=`) operator:

```
def write_file(path:str, client_socket:socket, open_mode: str = "wb"):
    with open(path, open_mode) as f:
        while data := client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN):
            f.write(data)
    client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")
```

Comment: That's an awesome assignment expression, thanks for sharing. However, sockets aren't friendly in this way unless I close my sending connection after the file send. This is much more elegant, but I never get to the ```not data``` state, because I'm not closing the sending socket after file is sent.

Comment: @J.Krajewski, you can also apply [`makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) to let socket module do all this job with buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You can let python do all work with buffered download using [`socket.makefile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile).

Code:

```
import socket
import shutil

def write_file(path:str, client_socket:socket, open_mode:str="wb"):
    with open(path, open_mode, BUFFER_LEN) as f, client_socket.makefile("rb", BUFFER_LEN) as sf:
        shutil.copyfileobj(sf, f)
    client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")
```

**Important notice.** This method will work properly only if server close connection after sending all content.

If you know size of file you can do next:

```
def write_file(path:str, client_socket:socket, file_size:int, open_mode: str="wb"):
    with open(path, open_mode, BUFFER_LEN) as f, client_socket.makefile("rb", BUFFER_LEN) as sf:
        f.write(sf.read(file_size))
    client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")
```

It will read exactly amount of bytes you've passed in `file_size` and doesn't require closing socket. You can pass file size in first few bytes of message. **But** it will load all data to memory, so this method you can apply only for smaller files. I can implement buffering but in that case there will be no difference with other answers, so I leaving it like it is.

Comment: This is interesting, however after implementing this, I still have the problem of a hanging socket. Because I am not closing the sending socket, I never get a close. Additionally, if I set buffering to false, it lasts forever. 

In the end I'm not sure if it's helping with my particular problem, but it's an interesting solution. Thank you

Comment: Secondly, when I used BUFFER_LEN, it stopped receiving after 4096bytes.

Comment: @J.Krajewski, but I've tested with BUFFER_LEN smaller than data I've received and it worked perfectly. Also, about hanging socket - you should close socket after function call if it's needed.

Comment: @J.Krajewski, check [this](https://repl.it/repls/ClientsideFlickeringUpgrade).

Comment: In my original post, I have the line ```if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN: break``` This is necessary to recover the hanging socket in my case. If I close the socket, it seems to complete the file, but if I don't, it hangs on me without writing the last buffer.

Comment: @J.Krajewski, you want to start download again if file not completely downloaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222128/discussion-between-j-krajewski-and-olvin-roght).

Answer (score 0):

This happens to work really quickly. The difference here is I stopped opening the file so many times, and it is only opened twice based on suggestions above.

The provided answers rely on closing the sending socket, whereas this one does not require the connection to be broken in order to successfully write the file of arbitrary file length.

```
def download(path, client_socket):

    while True:
            file_buffer = b""
            recv_len = 1
                    
            try:
                while recv_len:
                    data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
                    recv_len = len(data)

                    # Overwrite file if exists.
                    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(data)

                    if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN:
                        break

                    else:
                        with open(path, 'ab') as f:
                            while True:
                                data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_LEN)
                                recv_len = len(data)

                                # Append rest of data chunks
                                f.write(data)

                                if recv_len < BUFFER_LEN:
                                    break
                    break

                if not data:
                    break

                client_socket.send(b"Successfully saved file.")

            except:
                client_socket.send(b"File transfer failed.")
```